# Can I publish my WPF in windows store?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-store-apps

I have my WPF application developed. I want to deploy it and handle the updates every time I create new version.So I am thinking of pushing my WPF app to windows store.

In WPF I am using some windows desktop specific API's that are not supported in UWP apps anymore for example `System.Diagnostics.Process`.

Is there a way to publish my wpf application to windows store to manage deployment and upgrades?

**Edit for possible duplicate:**

This is different question because I have several .exe files downloaded from my wpf app and I want to launch then from my wpf app. (You can think of this wpf app as Steam or Facebook Gameroom ). And from several resources I came to conclusion UWP apps wont be able to achieve that functionality.([here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7291e9e5-b23c-438b-81cd-717fd1143209/running-exe-file-in-universal-windows?forum=wpdevelop))

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried *googling* for this? There is a lot of information and guidance by Microsoft

Comment: Check [Desktop to UWP Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)

Comment: yeah currently I am looking at it `Desktop App Converter (Desktop to UWP Bridge)`. Won't there be any problem if I use `Process`.

Comment: You'll have to try it. *Why* do you want to use `Process` anyway? What are you trying to do? Some things have no meaning for store applications

Comment: I need to launch external .exe files. So I am using `Process` here. Because it came out for me that I wont be able to run/launch external .exe files in UWP apps

Comment: Read this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge#Publish

Comment: *Why* do you want to launch external processes at all? Can you imagine a *phone app* launching processes? What are you trying to do? Anyway, this has already been answered

Comment: May be u didn't understand my question.Could you please read my question. I didn't mention I was trying to deploy it to phone. Its a WPF app(desktop app). Just to manage deployment and upgrades I am trying to publish it through windows store.

Comment: That's entirely different question. I have several .exe files downloaded from my wpf app and I want to launch then from my wpf app. (You can think of this wpf app as Steam or Facebook Gameroom )

Comment: @Default It's not a duplicate question! Connected question answer is not about problem of that question. Please remove that sign. I'm also searching for an answer for this question. Don't want to create another possible dup.

Comment: @Panagiotis-Kanavos It's not a duplicate question! Connected question answer is not about problem of that question. Please remove that sign. I'm also searching for an answer for this question. Don't want to create another possible dup.

Comment: @Mikolaytis the original was. The question was about `Process` and the store. Only UWP applications can be published at the store. The edit, everything from `Edit for possible duplicate:` downwards shows an attempt to hijack the store and treat it as a zip deployment mechanism, with process launching used to run the actual installers. That's not what the store is or how it works.

Comment: @Mikolaytis even after the edit, what the OP describes is a package manager, not Windows Store. There are duplicate questions about this too